# How to prevent that tags will be overwritten in docker private registries?

Tags: docker

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31605661/2777965) about preventing tag overwrite in docker hub.

When one pushes a tag to a private docker registry and the current tag exists then it will be overwritten. How to prevent this?

I have considered using a digest and other solutions, but this does not guarantee overwrites as one is still able to tag an image using a certain digest. I really would like to see an error and an exit code of 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to prevent the overwrite of tags by listing the existing tags using https://github.com/jessfraz/reg and exit the pipeline if there is a duplicate.